# jquery validation doesn't work for ajax loaded bootstrap modal dialog content

Tags: zend-framework2, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap with zend 2.
The content of the modal is retrieved through ajax call.
But the validation doesn't work at all, it submits without checking any field:

Here is where the modal loads:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="themesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the modal content:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="themesbox">
        <div class="panel panel-info">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">title</div>
            </div>

            <div style="padding-top: 30px" class="panel-body">
                           <?php
                                $form = $this->form;
                                $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user/default', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'create')));
                                $form->prepare();
                                echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
                                ?>

                                <div id="mydiv"
                    style="display: none" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <p>Error:</p>
                    <span></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-md-3 control-label">user</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('name'));?>
                                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="col-md-3 control-label">password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">

                                        <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('password'));?>
                                    </div>
                </div>


                <div style="margin-top: 10px" class="form-group">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                    <?php echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));?>
                    <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag();?>  
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /. panel panel-info -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery validation code:

```
 $('.form-validation').each(function () {
     $(this).validate({


    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",   

    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        $(element).attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 1px solid;");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        $(element).attr('style', "border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid #ccc;");
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(error).attr('style', "color: #FF0000;");
        if ( element.prop('type') === 'checkbox') {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }

  });
 });
```

And here is the form code:

```
 $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',

            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'id' => 'username',
                'class'  => 'form-control',
                'required'  => 'true',
                'minlength'  => '8',
                'maxlength'  => '20',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'name',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'description',

            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'password',
                'id' => 'password',
                'class'  => 'form-control',
                'required'  => 'true',
                'minlength'  => '8',
                'maxlength'  => '20',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Password',
            ),
        ));
```

Comment: Instead of showing the Zend code, show the relevant  HTML markup as seen by the browser.

Comment: @Sparky I can the js script that holds the above js code included in the html

Comment: Showing the relevant HTML "proves" that the markup is suitable for the JavaScript.  How else are we supposed to determine why your jQuery Validate script is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a matter of fact all the server side validation mechanisms were in place and were working perfectly.

I needed client side validations through **jquery**.

Because the content of **Bootstrap** modal dialog is loading from **ajax**, it didn't consider the surrounding context as usual, I needed to insert **jquery** code in the ajax content.

**ZF2** doesn't permit inserting **js** code in its view files.

So I did in the following way inserting the following line in the **ajax** content:

```
 <?php echo $this->inlineScript()->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/js/custom.js')?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this working using a different method.

Rather than try to do your own validation on the client side (adding the error HTML etc) you should submit the form via AJAX and let ZF2 return a `JsonModel` with the form's markup.

If you are using the correct view helpers (`FormRow` specifically) it will correctly render the form errors.

For example

```
class FooController extends AbstractActionController
{

   public function createAction()
   {
     $request = $this->getRequest();
     $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FooService'); 
     $form    = $service->getFooCreateForm(); // Zend\Form

     if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $foo = $service->create($form->getData());

            if ($foo instanceof Foo)
                // redirect to success page
            } else {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Error!');
            }
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('foo', array('action' => 'index'));

        } else if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

            $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer');
            $formView = new ViewModel(compact('form')); // add the form to the view
            $formView->setTemplate('foo-module/foo/form');

            return new JsonModel(array(
                'success' => false, // Flag to keep modal open
                'content' => $renderer->render($formView), // The "content" being the form HTML
                'message' => 'Please check all form fields have been completed successfully',
            ));
        }
     }
     return new ViewModel(compact('form'));
   }

}
```

**form.phtml**

```
<?php
  echo $this->form($this->form);
```

**create.phtml**

```
//...modal html
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo $this->partial('form.phtml', compact('form')); ?>
</div>
//... modal html
```

And you would also want to:

- Remove any buttons from the ZF2 forms (as the modal already has two)
- Add an JS event listener to the modal submit button and AJAX post the form content
  to the `createAction`
- If the result of the call is `success == true` then close the modal
- If the result is `success == false` you will have the `content` variable which can then replace the existing modal content using `$('.modal-content').html(result.content)` This will include the validated form HTML (including all the errors generated view the form view helpers).

Comment: Although a good idea to always have server-side validation, in this case the OP is asking about client-side validation.  Typically both are used; client-side for a better user experience and server-side in case the former fails.

Comment: @Sparky The "better experience" your referring to is to avoid a page refresh right? This approach submits the form *via AJAX* and builds the HTML using the form view helpers; No page reload; all you would need to do is replace the form content with the response from the AJAX call. This in my opinion is better than duplicating possibly complex validation serverside (where you have to add HTML content via javascript). That would be hard to maintain and extend - if you were to add a field to the form for instance.

Comment: My main point is simply that your solution does not specifically address the OP's question.